# ConstraintLayout enforce top constraint with loose bottom constraint

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout file:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:background="#00CCBB"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="center" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#0074CC"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I wanted to achieve is that the `bottom` view stays in the bottom of the screen if the screen space allows, but push the `bottom` views according to the top constraint of the `bottom`. So if the layout is smaller, I want the `bottom` view moving toward the bottom part of the layout (basically having layout param `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` set to `0`).

I think it is possible to solve this by checking if the view bounds intersects using code, but I'm looking for xml solution. Is it possible to do this only by xml?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you post something visual?